# Getting unexpected black background after applying style:"stroke: blue; stroke-width: 2px;"

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, graph, dagre-d3, dagre

I'm new to reactJS and I have been trying to create a graph in react using DagreGraph.
I learnt minimum react required to understand how to create a graph. This is my code that is giving errors with the edge that is created between two nodes.

```
import DagreGraph from "dagre-d3-react";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
// import d3 from "dagre-d3";
var nodes = [
  {
    id: "1",
    label: "<h3>Node 1</h3>",
    labelType: "html",
    config: {
      style: "fill: #bef3a6"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    label: "<h3>Node 2</h3>",
    labelType: "html",
    config: {
      style: "fill: #f3a6a6"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    label: "<h3>Node 3</h3>",
    labelType: "html",
    config: {
      style: "fill:#1111"
    }
  }
];
var links = [
  {
    source: "1",
    target: "2",   
    config:{
      style:"stroke: blue; stroke-width: 2px;", 
      lineInterpolate:'basis', 
      arrowheadStyle:"fill: blue",      
    }
  },  
  {
    source: "2",
    target: "3",   
    config:{
      style:"stroke: blue; stroke-width: 2px;", 
      lineInterpolate:'basis', 
      arrowheadStyle:"fill: blue", 
    }
  },
  {
    source: "1",
    target: "3",   
    config:{
      style:"stroke: blue; stroke-width: 2px;", 
      lineInterpolate:'basis', 
      arrowheadStyle:"fill: blue", 
      arrowhead:"vee",
      fill:"blue"
    }
  }
];
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <DagreGraph
      nodes={nodes}
      links={links}
      options={{
        rankdir: "LR",
        align: "UL",
        ranker: "tight-tree"
      }}
      width="500"
      height="500"     
      animate={1000}
      fitBoundaries
      zoomable
      onNodeClick={(e) => console.log(e)}
      onRelationshipClick={(e) => console.log(e)}
    />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This is my code to create 3 nodes using DagreGraph from "dagre-d3-react" in react.
I'm not able to get the graph as expected. I'm getting **black** background for the arrows which should not be there as in here
[DagreGraph](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DKL5biN-_1XrBz1JPpxzTZ6dkz_G0sGq7XomCZwKBSU/edit?usp=sharing)
Could you please help me in finding out the error in my code?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found solution to my question.
Gotta change the style attribute to this for every link

```
config:{
      style:"stroke: blue; stroke-width: 2px;fill:none", 
      lineInterpolate:'basis', 
      arrowheadStyle:"fill: blue",      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the fill as none for all arrows and it will solve it:

```
      style: " fill:none;stroke:#200e32;stroke-width:2px;",
```